# Need to change variable values using node module functions and then use these variables to render ejs file. Where should I put these variables?

Tags: node.js

My file structure is: app.js, modules.js and view.ejs.

I have some variables in app.js. Then functions from modules change the values of these variables. Finally I pass these vars while rendering ejs.

The problem I am facing is that to change the value of these vars from module functions I am having to create setter functions inside app.js. Is this the right way to do it? It clutters the app.js again. also I am having to pass these 10 or so vars into those module functions as params. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Not a lot of context here. Modules “changing” variables they don’t own seems odd. Passing ten variables to anything implies a missing abstraction. There’s no way to know what makes sense without context, though.

Comment: Hey Dave, I have an array say "words" in app.js file, and a module func that generates a new word and saves it to array. Hence the module changing the var. Then I pass the array to ejs to populate the page. Now the module func is not able to add new word to the array by using arr.push(foo). So I have to create a setter func in app.js and give it as callback to module func. Where would be the best place to declare this array? in app.js or in module.js. How should I go about it? Or is this normal?

Comment: Why not pass the array to the function that modifies it? Or create a function that gets a word from the module and pushes it?